# JS : How to replace duplicated elements in array with new values

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I ve an array which looks like this :

```
let arr = ['11','44','66','88','77','00','66','11','66']
```

as visible , inside this array , there were those duplicated elements :

- '11' in position 7
- '66' in positions 6 and 8

I want to iterate over my array , so that , i find the duplicated elements ; and replace them from the second occurence with a string indicating the first occurrence index

my resulting array would like this :

```
let newarr = ['11','44','66','88','77','00','appears at 2','appears at 0','appears at 2']
```

as you can this the duplications are replaced with a string like this :

"appears at n" **where** "**n**" is the index of the first occurence

Comment: what does not work - actually?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: Please don't spam the tags; either you're targeting browsers that support ES5 or those supporting ES6, or you're relying on TypeScript to transpile for you, in which case neither tag is warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const appearances = {}
const arr = ['11','44','66','88','77','00','66','11','66']

const newarr = arr.map((item, index) => {
  if (appearances[item] !== undefined) return `appears at ${appearances[item]}`
  else {
    appearances[item] = index
    return item
  }
})

console.log("new arr: ", newarr)
```

Answer (score 1):

A short approach with a closure over a hash table for the indices and a conditional operator

```js
const
    array = ['11', '44', '66', '88', '77', '00', '66', '11', '66'],
    result = array.map(
        (indices => (v, i) => (indices[v] ??= i) == i ? v : `seen at ${indices[v]}`)
        ({})
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a two-step method that:

1. creates an object that records first occurences
2. maps source array to new array with substitutions

```js
let arr = ['11', '44', '66', '88', '77', '00', '66', '11', '66'];

// record first occurences
const firsts = arr.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
  if (typeof acc[val] === 'undefined') {
    acc[val] = index;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log('firsts:', firsts);

// create array with substitutions
const newarr = arr.map((val, index) => {
  return (firsts[val] === index) ? val
    : `appears at ${firsts[val]}`
});

console.log(`newarr:`, newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```js
let arr = ["11", "44", "66", "88", "77", "00", "66", "11", "66"].map(
  (value, index, self) => {
    if (self.indexOf(value, 0) !== index) {
      return `appears at ${self.indexOf(value, 0)}`;
    }
    return value;
  }
);
console.log(arr);
```